# Casting strings to numbers in App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

The title is perhaps misleading but I don't know how this is called. I do want to know how to type cast for example an int variable to create a string `image_number`, where number is the value of that variable.

But the thing that bothers me the most is how to call for example an `imageSprite` with a string constructed in similar way.

I have 16 sprites in a list and some for loops, and have trouble calling sprites. I want to for example check whether that particular sprite has an image set. I know I can use the block that tells me whether that's the case or not, but I want to say:

if the number you are increasing is n, I want you to check whether `imageSprite_n` has an image set or not (without using if number == n, use `imageSprite_n`).

I hope my question is clear. Is there any way to do that or should this be done without a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn how to work with lists

- [How to work with Lists](http://www.imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/list-blocks-on-app-inventor/) by Saj
- [How to work with Lists and Lists of
  lists](http://www.appinventor.org/bookChapters/chapter19.pdf) (pdf) by [appinventor.org](http://www.appinventor.org/)

and [learn how to use the advanced blocks](https://puravidaapps.com/tutorials.php#advanced)

Then you can do it like this

[image]

The example uses 4 image sprites and checks, if image sprite 3 has an image set